# Getting a particular arraylist element

Tags: java

**Can a moderator please delete or lock this question, i know the answer now and i didn't ask the questions every clearly

OK sorry ill post everything in my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MinorAssignment_PartB {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<StudentMarks> marks = new ArrayList<StudentMarks>();
        String File = "studentinfo.txt";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(File));
        scan.useDelimiter(",");//makes the delimiter a comma

        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            marks.add(new StudentMarks(scan.next(), scan.next(),
                            scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble(),
                            scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble()));

            System.out.printf("%-23s %-15s %-15s %-15s " +
                    "%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %n", "STUDENT  NAME",
                        "STUDENT FAN", "PART A", "PART B", "PARTt C",
                                            "PART D", "MARK", "GRADE");

            for (int i = 0; i < marks.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(marks.get(i));
            }
        }
```

and the class

```
import java.text.*;

public class StudentMarks {

    //contains a student class and an array of doubles. 
    private Student student = new Student();
    private double marks[] = new double[5];
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");

    public StudentMarks(String name, String fan,
            double partA, double partB, double partC, double partD) {
        Student stud = new Student(name, fan);
        this.student = stud;
        this.marks[0] = partA;
        this.marks[1] = partB;
        this.marks[2] = partC;
        this.marks[3] = partD;
        this.marks[4] = ((partA*0.1) + (partB*0.4) + (partC*0.2) + (partD*0.3));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + student + "\t" + marks[0] + "\t\t" + marks[1] + "\t\t" + marks[2] + "\t\t" + marks[3] + "\t\t" + fmt.format(marks[4])+"%";
    }
}
```

So i need to get a particular element in a line of arraylist

i have 10 lines of text with each line containing 2 string and 2 doubles like this
Adam Adamson       adam0001     85.4       79.8      82.4      86.1
9 more lines the same format differnt names and numbers

i have marks.get(0) which print the first line but i need just the 3rd element, 85.4

Thanx everyone for trying but i figured it out, sorry for not asking the questions very clearly

Comment: Could you post the definition of this ArrayList? It looks like it may be a list containing another list.

Comment: You need to tell us what the datatype of marks is, and describe the objects it contains.

Comment: Are you going to show us the code? Else you are really wasting your time. We can't help you much currently.

Comment: @Rohit Jain yes with out code, we need to assume a lot

Comment: how do i make return/enters actually work when im writing the questions, i had a return/enter before adam adamson but didnt go to a new line

Comment: Please do not write the code, as if every one watching the code, use to work on a 32" monitor, there are some, who use to work on 14" or below too :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll have to add following getter to access `marks` in `StudentMarks`;

```
public double[] getMarks() {
    return this.marks;
}
```

Then, you can use following code snippet to get value `85.4` i.e `partA`.

```
StudentMarks info = marks.get(0);
double[] marksValue = info.getMarks();
double partA = marksValue[0];
```

`partA` is required variable with value `85.4` which you may use as per your requirement.

Comment: Sorry the Adam Adamson info is one line of 10, if i put 2 there it will print out line 3 which is a different persons information

Comment: i put that and there is a red underlined error on the first line saying string required StudentMarks found, StudentMarks is the name of my Array

Comment: Get `StudentMarks` object from array and get the needed value from it.

Comment: @user2828122 Post the defition for `StudentMarks`

Answer (score 0):

try converting

```
Person person =(person)marks.get(0);
System.out.println(person.StudentMarks[0]);
```

and then get the attribute you need

Comment: yeah probably, the question is not clear. I guess question will be updated soon

Answer (score 0):

Define a getter method in your `StudentMarks` class:

```
public double[] getMarks() {
    return marks;
}
```

And use `System.out.println(marks.get(i).getMarks()[0]);` if your `marks[0]` is the value you need.