# Get element in array in arraylist

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to be concise.  I couldn't find answers online, though I'm sure they're there, but I reviewed these questions on SO and didn't find what I was looking for:

[compare-and-retrieve-elements-from-arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904569/compare-and-retrieve-elements-from-arraylist)

[getting-index-of-an-item-in-an-arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393709/getting-index-of-an-item-in-an-arraylist)

[getting-a-particular-arraylist-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078341/getting-a-particular-arraylist-element)

I have an `ArrayList` with a number of arrays in them, each of which are one-dimensional and have varying amounts of elements (both string and int).  How can I access the elements in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: Please remove the arraylist tag if it doesn't apply. While C# does have a class under System.Collections called ArrayList, the tag explicitly cites Java, so I'm not sure if I should use it.

Comment: What type of elements do you want to access ?  all elements inside of one-dimensional arrays ?

Comment: The ArrayList contains lists of arrays. Those arrays have varying numbers of items in them. The items in any of those arrays can be either strings or integers, and may appear in different configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OfType` and `SelectMany`,for example you can get all `string` and `integer` values inside of *one-dimensional* arrays like this:

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
arr.Add(new []{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
arr.Add(new [] {"asdas", "asdsa"});
var stringValues = arr.OfType<Array>()
                      .SelectMany(x => x.OfType<string>());  // asdas asdsa
var intValues = arr.OfType<Array>()
                   .SelectMany(x => x.OfType<string>());  // 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I can't find the methods OfType or SelectMany. I am not familiar with Linq, but it looks like (according to the answer below) that might be what you are talking about.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... what version of .NET Framework you are using? add a reference to System.Linq.dll, `using System.Linq`

Comment: The *using* statement works and I am using version 4.0.  I didn't know any references added methods to other references. The Linq import added OfType(), but it did not add SelectMany().

Comment: it is not _possible_, `SelectMany` is supported in 4.0 see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx), and also SelectMany and OfType are in the same assembly.You are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... SelectMany method doesn't take ArrayList  as first parameter.You should use OfType or Cast methods to access that method because it takes `IEnumerable<T>`.See my answer, did I use Arraylist.SelectMany ?

Comment: You see `OfType` because it takes `IEnumerable` as first parameter not `IEnumerable<T>`, and `ArrayList` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>` because it is not **generic**

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... why don't you just try this answer and see it is correct or wrong?

Comment: Copying it doesn't teach me it and I can't use it effectively if the first thing i try to do on my own fails. I'm going to try and figure out what's going on there.

Comment: Okay, now that I known about extension methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), I know where SelectMany() came from. I learned that the IEnumerable interface just deals with overloading the indexing operator []. (As you can see, I am still learning C#.) I now understand this code; thanks. It works for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Linq has an extension method SelectMany that will make it look like all the child lists are one list

array.SelectMany( i => i );